# Recycler view only showing one item

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to write data to a file using recycler view the data is being passed but as soon as new data is passed it gets overwritten with the new data when it should instead show the new data and the old. I can see in the file all the previous data collected but I want the recycler view to show all of the data too. Here is my code.

```
package com.example.pigdicegame

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import java.io.*
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.*

const val LeaderBoard_File = "LeaderBoard.txt"

class leaderboard : AppCompatActivity() {

   private lateinit var btnSwitchBack: Button
   private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
   private var leaderList = ArrayList<LeaderBoardItem>()
   private lateinit var LeaderBoardadapter: LeaderBoardadapter

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_leaderboard)

       btnSwitchBack = findViewById(R.id.btnSwitchBack)
       recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.leaderboardRecycler)

       LeaderBoardadapter = LeaderBoardadapter(leaderList)
       recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)
       recyclerView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
       recyclerView.adapter = LeaderBoardadapter

       try {
           val extras = intent.extras
           if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("Score") && extras.containsKey("CompScore")) {
               readLogData()

               val score: Int = extras.getInt("Score", 0)
               val compScore: Int = extras.getInt("CompScore", 0)

               val formatter =
                   DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMMM-yyyy ", Locale.getDefault())
               val formattedDate = LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter)

               val date = LocalDate.now()

               // Append the data to the file
               val file = File(filesDir, LeaderBoard_File)

               try {
                   val fileWriter = FileWriter(file, true)
                   val bufferedWriter = BufferedWriter(fileWriter)

                   bufferedWriter.write("You : $score  $formattedDate\nComputer : $compScore  $formattedDate\n")
                   bufferedWriter.close()

                   // Add the new entry to the list
                   leaderList.add(LeaderBoardItem(score, compScore, date))

                   // Sort the list in reverse order (newest game first)
                   leaderList.reverse()

                   // Notify the adapter that the data has changed
                   LeaderBoardadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
               } catch (e: IOException) {
                   e.printStackTrace()
               }
           }
       } catch (e: Exception) {
           e.printStackTrace()
       }
   }


   private fun readLogData() {
       try {
           val file = File(filesDir, LeaderBoard_File)
           if (file.exists()) {
               // Clear the existing list before adding data
               //leaderList.clear()

               val lines = file.readText().split("\n")

               for (line in lines) {
                   println("Line: $line")
                   val parts = line.split(":")
                   if (parts.size >= 2) {
                       val scoreAndDate = parts[1].trim().split(" ")
                       if (scoreAndDate.size == 2) {
                           val leaderItem = LeaderBoardItem(scoreAndDate[0].toInt(), 0, LocalDate.parse(scoreAndDate[1]))
                           leaderList.add(leaderItem)
                       }
                   }
               }

               // Sort the list in reverse order (newest game first)
               leaderList.reverse()

               // Notify the adapter that the data has changed
               LeaderBoardadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
           }
       } catch (e: Exception) {
           e.printStackTrace()
       }
   }


   fun btnSwitchBackOnClick(v: View) {
       val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
       btnSwitchBack.isEnabled = false
       startActivity(intent)
   }
}
```

I would like all the data to be shown in the recycler view. But it is only showing one item at a time but it should show a list.

Comment: Please show us your adapter code as well. There may be something wrong when binding or getting the adapter's size

Answer (score -1):

First of All check data within your list. How much object comes within your list. Second check and give Adapter getItemCount with itemList.size, third check your single item xml rootView height to Wrapcontent or not.

Comment: @nightowl989 bro where's the problem,  why you giving me negative point.